# ruby and selenium-webdriver on raspberry pi -> Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)

Tags: ruby, exception, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi

I want to run a ruby scrip on my Raspberry Pi. I've installed ruby via rvm. I'm sure, I'm using the right version:

```
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

when i run my script, then i get following:

```
./test.rb 
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `initialize': Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `new'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `block in free?'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:23:in `each'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:23:in `free?'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:5:in `above'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
from ./test.rb:82:in `block in <main>'
from ./test.rb:54:in `each'
from ./test.rb:54:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas, what is wrong? I've tried to restart, this doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for questions like this.